# Is it possible to turn a View-Based App into a navigation-Based App?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, view, navigation

I am close to finishing my first application (a UITableView style one) on the iphone but have realised it will look much better, and stand a far better chance of getting through the approval process, if it is presented as a navigation-based app rather than a view-based one - in hindsight my initial choice is not really suitable...

Is it possible for me to somehow change easily the application into a new type, or would i be better starting again from scratch with all the hassle that would entail...

thanks for any advice on how it may be done,
karl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't be particularly difficult to shift the means of interaction to a navigation controller from a simple view controller (it also isn't difficult to go the reverse direction). Although, there isn't anything as simple as a tutorial on how to do it or menu item you can select. You could look at the plumbing generated by Apple's template for a navigation based application and add the necessary glue to your app delegate. Once that is in place you could simply push your view based applications view controller onto the navigation stack. If you have more specific questions or are stuck somewhere in particular we can help to get you un-stuck if you provide details about where you are running into issues.

As an aside, I doubt your application will be rejected solely for being view based vs. navigation based.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmm, for soem reason t wont let me add anything to comment on your post!

Anyway, i guess this is as good as anything here...

Ive been messing for the last hour or so and have managed to integrate my old code/data etc into a new navigation one without too many problems, in fact it looks nicer with a title bar at the top!

(I do like to try and work stuff out for myself so its a good learning curve!)

I am still struggling in that although the new view opens up i am

1. struggling to use a string from the first view (I have a UITableview table in there, i select a row and get a correct value from it which i currently check via an alert message) in the second view.
2. for some reason i do not get a title bar and 'back' button in the 2nd view so i guess it is not being put on the stack correctly (I have put a quick 'return' button in the view for testing purposes so i can navigate backwards and forwards).

Still, Im about 100% further on than i was earlier!

cheers for the reply,
Karl